# How to get all formulas of a sheet in office.js

Tags: office-js, office-addins

Having a sheet name say `Sheet1`, I want to have an array of all formulas used in cells of that sheet. Something like this:

```
Excel.run(function (ctx) {
    var formulas = getAllFormulasOfSheet(ctx, 'Sheet1')
    // or
    getAllFormulasOfSheet(ctx, 'Sheet1').then(function(result){
        var formulas = result;
    });

    // formulas should be like:
    ['SUM(A1:B3)', 'SUM(A3:C3)']
})
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Getting usedRange formulas may be more reasonable as you don't need the entire sheer's formula. Below script will result in 2-D array formula being returned for used range. `[['=sum(a1:b2)', '=sum(a2:b2)']]`. You can also load `formulaR1C1` or `formulaLocal` if you need them. Retrieval of unbounded range is not supported (entire row, col, sheet). You have to call usedRange() method on them to get all useful cells.

```
async function getFormulas() {
    try {
        await Excel.run(async (context) => {
            const sheet = context.workbook.worksheets.getItem("Sample");
            const range = sheet.getUsedRange();
            // const range = sheet.getRange("B2:E6"); //if you need specific address. You can also use named item based fetch.
            range.load("formulas");

            await context.sync();

            console.log(JSON.stringify(range.formulas, null, 4));
        });
    }
    catch (error) {
        //handle error
    }
}
```

Comment: This way I get the formulas but I will not able to track the cell in which this formula is used

Answer (score 2):

*(Sudhi's answer is correct and was first, so it should be the "Accepted" answer. I'm adding this one to provide some supplemental info.)*

As Sudhi's answer suggests, you should use the `Worksheet.GetUsedRange()` method to get the range of the worksheet that's actually been used, and then reference the `formulas` property of that range to identify the formulas that the range contains.

Please note, however, that the `Range.formulas` property will contain an array of arrays that has contents of *all* cells in the range -- not just the formulas in the range. For example, if the worksheet contains this data, where only the cells in range `E3:E5` and cells in range `C6:E6` contain formulas:

[image]

Then the `Range.formulas` property for the "used range" of the worksheet will return this JSON:

```
[
    [
        "Product",
        "Qty",
        "Unit Price",
        "Total Price"
    ],
    [
        "Almonds",
        2,
        7.5,
        "=C3*D3"
    ],
    [
        "Coffee",
        1,
        34.5,
        "=C4*D4"
    ],
    [
        "Chocolate",
        5,
        9.56,
        "=C5*D5"
    ],
    [
        "TOTAL",
        "=SUM(C3:C5)",
        "=SUM(D3:D5)",
        "=SUM(E3:E5)"
    ]
]
```

I've created a gist that you can use with Script Lab (a free add-in you can get here: aka.ms/getscriptlab) to see how this all works. Once you've installed the Script Lab add-in in Excel, open the Script Lab **Code** pane there, select **Import** from the menu, and then import this gist:  https://gist.github.com/kbrandl/01858318da8cbdff606e8bba32145882.

Comment: JS API should implement Range.SpecialCells to efficiently solve this and related problems.